# Hyper-ledger fabric genesis block related

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyper-ledger fabric, in which directory is the genesis block and ledger stored and how can I move them from docker to my own Hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

you could check the Environments of a running orderer container.
e.g -

```
docker exec -it <orderere container name> sh

env
```

There you could see the **ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE**  environment variable pointing to genesis file inside that orderer container.

Now you could copy that file using docker copy command :
e.g:

```
docker cp orderer1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block ./
```

This answer is based on Hyperledger Fabric version: 1.4.9